How to read SwagDynamicAccess rule specific entity data within Shopware 6 app script?
I have a simple navigation-page-loaded app script that reads categories like this:
{% set categoryEntities = services.repository.search('category', criteria) %}

However, one category that matches the current criteria object doesn't meet the rule specific requirements set via a SwagDynamicAccess rule. Currently it is loaded anyway.
E.g. the rule of one category says:

Language > contains > English

If the storefront language is German the category via the app script is loaded anyway via the repository, even though it shouldn't since it doesn't match the rule.
Is there a way to conisder SwagDynamicAccess rules whithin the app system on a category basis?
